# How to load data concurrently with TaskGroup in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, async-await, concurrency

I have array of objects 'Games' some fields of game have ids property of different types of objects. I need to load these object async by ids, to have fully loaded game with objects.

```
struct Game: Codable {
  var field1: Int
  var field2: Int
  var field1Object: Object1?
  var field2Object: Object2?
  .....
}

func fetchData(_ games: [Game]) async -> [Game] {
   await withTaskGroup(of: Game.self) { group in
        var updatedGames = [Game]()
        updatedGames.reserveCapacity(games.count)
        for game in games {
            group.addTask {
                let field1Object = await loadObjectBy(game.field1)
                game.field1Object = field1Object
                return game
            }
            group.addTask {
                let field2Object = await loadObjectBy(game.field2)
                game.field2Object = field2Object
                return game
            }
        }
        for await updatedGame in group {
            updatedGames.append(updatedGame)
        }
        return updatedGames
    }
}
```

I have error 'game is let constant', How to correctly load object? Can I modify game in addTask closure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'shop' is a 'let' constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74603467/swiftui-cannot-use-mutating-member-on-immutable-value-shop-is-a-let-consta)

Answer (score 2):

The error "game is let constant" is a duplicated issue. For example, see this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74603997/18557672

**game is the element iterated inside the loop, it's just a copy, and of course it only exists inside the loop's closure.**

To access and modify a specific element of the "games" var inside the closure, you need to implement your code with that in mind. You could maybe use (as suggested by @Rob):

```
for index in games.indices {
    ...
    games[index]
    ...
}
```

You should try to fix that issue first, and then, if you still have problems with the original task, try to edit the question with the updated info.

Comment: Thanks, actually here is the post that solved all my question:
https://www.donnywals.com/running-tasks-concurrently-with-swift-concurrencys-async-let/

Comment: I assume you meant `for (index, game) in games.enumerated() { … }`. Or better `for index in games.indices { … }`. Probably better to not mutate `games` at all...

Comment: Please note that you do not "update questions or close them as solved" on Stack Overflow. Questions contain questions only, not solutions. Answers (such as this one) exist to provide solutions, and askers can provide their own answer to their own question if they find the solution themselves (although simply providing a link is insufficient for an answer). Answers can be accepted by the asker to indicate a working or best solution, but that does not "close" the question; future answers can still be added to the thread.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn more about how the site works.